# Angular google maps not loading after upgrading to wkwebview

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I have had just had to upgrade the keyboard plugin on my ionic 1 app, from `ionic-plugin-keyboard` to `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard`, since the former has been deprecated. To do this upgrade, I had to also install the `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` plugin, since `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard` has a dependency on it.

I am now experiencing a strange issue though, where any maps (using angular-google-maps), don't display if opened in a modal, however, they do display if opened in any normal view.

There are no errors in the console at all, and I simply can't figure this out.

I am using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js v3.32.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using google maps version 3.31 fixes the issue for some reason, unfortunately, I have no idea why this is.